# ¿Cómo se traduce "dowager"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, palabras-raras, solicitud-de-término

La palabra inglesa "**dowager**" no parece tener una traducción fácil. La principal acepción, que es la que me interesa, corresponde a "viuda", pero con matices muy concretos:

La definición de [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/dowager) es

> A woman of high social rank whose husband is dead but who has a title and property because of her marriage to him: a dowager queen

En [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-spanish/dowager) lo traducen como

> 1 (widow) viuda de un noble

En [Babylon](http://traductor.babylon-software.com/ingles/dowager/), como

> viuda de título

Parece que la traducción sería, por tanto, "**viuda de un noble**" o "**viuda de título**".

Sin embargo, en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowager) aparece una definición más amplia:

> A dowager is a widow who holds a title or property—a "dower"—derived from her deceased husband. As an adjective, dowager usually appears in association with monarchical and aristocratic titles.

Sin embargo, a continuación introduce una explicacion acerca de su uso:

> In the United Kingdom, the widow of a peer may continue to use the style she had during her husband's lifetime, e.g. "Countess of Loamshire", **provided that his successor, if any, has no wife to bear the plain title. Otherwise she more properly prefixes either her forename or the word Dowager, e.g. "Jane, Countess of Loamshire" or "Dowager Countess of Loamshire"** (In any case she would continue to be called "Lady Loamshire").

Comment: Si quiere traducir "Dowager Countess", yo le sugiero "condesa viuda" o "viuda condesa"; expresiones que especifican a la vez título y condición de viudez.  Si requiere algo más general, podría usar "herederas", "matronas", etc.

Comment: No tengo a la mano mi ejemplar en español pero en el libro 1Q84 de Murakami hay un personaje que en inglés se llama "the Dowager." Olvido qué palabra que se usó en español pero creo que sería otra posibilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesantísima palabra, que nunca había oído en inglés.

A simple vista parece que no hay una palabra española exactamente equivalente, por lo que la respuesta correcta creo que es: no hay tal palabra.

Sin embargo, con la explicación que mencionas de la Wikipedia, especialmente en negrita, me viene a la cabeza la palabra **regente**:

> [**regente, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ViPk1u4)
>   *Del lat. regens, -entis.*
>   1. adj. Que rige (‖ gobierna). U. t. c. s.
>   ...
>   3. m. y f. Persona que gobierna un Estado en la menor edad de un príncipe o por otro motivo.

Donde la clave está en el verbo **regentar**:

> [**regentar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ViM5K5s)
>   1. tr. Desempeñar temporalmente ciertos cargos o empleos.

Juntando las definiciones de adjetivo y verbo damos con el hecho de que un regente es alguien que ostenta un cargo temporalmente.

Sé que el uso de *regente* casi siempre se usa en su 3ª acepción, pero no por ello creo menos conveniente sugerir esta palabra como lo más cercano a la palabra *dowager*, aunque sea por simple correspondencia en la definición.

Comment: That is an ingenious suggestion but she does not usually have any formal powers. I wonder whether _honorario_ or _de honor_ might be possible here although it is not by any means an exact equivalent.

Comment: @mdewey uhms, in Spain they do have powers. Or at least [they did](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_Cristina_de_Habsburgo-Lorena#Regencia). But yes, I agree this is a bit far away from _dowager_.

Comment: @fedorqui: yo me tropecé con esta palabra al leer una biografía de Cixi

Comment: @fedorqui, sorry I meant the dowager does not have powers, our regents had powers too just like the example you mention.

Comment: @user13560 veo que la wiki la define simplemente como _emperatriz viuda_

Comment: @mdewey ah, I see. So a _dowager_ has a title that is just symbolic, without any power attached to it.

Comment: @fedorqui: Cixi, como Ci'an, era una de las "emperatrices viudas" que dejó el emperador, sin poder real como señala mdewey - aunque en la realidad si lo tuvo al ser co-regente de los siguientes nuevos emperadores mientras fueron menores de edad.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión que buscas creo que es **consorte viudo o viuda**.

Por un lado, tenemos:

> **[consorte](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AQnYIBO)**
>
> Del lat. *consors, -ortis* 'participante'.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que recibe el título, condición, nombre de la profesión, etc., por razón de matrimonio con la persona que los posee por derecho propio. *Rey, duquesa consorte.* U. t. c. s.

Por otro lado, sobre el término "consorte", en España se define por una parte el concepto de reina consorte de España, de cual [se dice que es](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reina_consorte_de_Espa%C3%B1a) un título de carácter:

> Vitalicio (en caso de enviudar, conserva el título, la dignidad y el tratamiento correspondientes)

Por otra parte, sobre el término aplicado a la nobleza [se dice](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consorte):

> En el caso de los títulos nobiliarios los cónyuges de duques, marqueses, condes etc. reciben el mismo tratamiento y honores que los titulares de dichas mercedes ya sean varones o mujeres. Los cónyuges viudos mantienen dichos tratamientos mientras permanezcan en tal estado, perdiéndolo en caso de contraer nuevas nupcias.

Comment: Estoy en desacuerdo con esta respuesta, @carlos-alejo.  La palabra dowager en inglés, según la pregunta, es usada generalmente en combinación con un título y en referencia a la viuda.  La expresión "consorte viuda" no identifica el título, tampoco lo hace "viuda de un noble".  Yo sugiero que la traducción sería, e.g., "condesa viuda" o "marquesa viuda", etc.  Expresiones que dan a la vez,  el específico título de nobleza y la condición de viudez, como generalmente es usado en inglés.  Otros usos en inglés sin especificidad de título, podría traducirse como heredera, matrona, etc.

Comment: @David el usuario preguntó por la traducción de "dowager". Al igual que la palabra "dowager" necesita ir seguida del título (*dowager queen*), también es necesario que "consorte viudo" se asocie al título: *reina consorte viuda*.

Comment: +1 ahora que comprendo mejor tu respuesta.  Gracias.